# Microsoft Online Document Viewer ( Office Web Viewer) not working

Tags: viewer, documentviewer

We are using Microsoft Office Online document viewer to view doc/docx documents from a URL.
This was working till yesterday.

However the functionality has stopped working from today ( 25th August 2021). Word logo comes up however the document is not shown.

The URL we used was [https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?wdPrint=0&src={URL](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?wdPrint=0&src=%7BURL) of document}
We tried with alternative URLs such as [https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src={doucment](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=%7Bdoucment) URL} but it shows sorry there was a problem prompt. If the document is downloaded from URL and opened in word, it works correctly.

Anybody else facing similar issues ?

Comment: Yes we  tried the same too and the issue remains. As an alternative we tried Google document viewer https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&amp;url={URL} . Though it works sometimes, generally it seems unstable and shows blank page every other attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been with some service within Microsoft and the same seems to have been fixed now. Hence documents are viewable.